# getting multiple API calls in one variable using for loop in Flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

am trying to get user favorites categories to customize the home page with it instead of showing all categories. First am getting the favorites categories of the user in list then am for looping my API get service with the categories as parameters but when the loop end only the data from the last loop index shows. I wanna know why? and how to achieve my desired output.

Am using Flutter 2.0.4

This is my API Call

```
Future<APIResponse<List<NewsModel>>> getByCategory(String category) {
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
};
return http
    .get(Uri.parse('$api/articales/$category'), headers: headers)
    .then((data) {
  if (data.statusCode == 200) {
    final jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    final articales = <NewsModel>[];
    for (final item in jsonData) {
      articales.add(NewsModel.fromJson(item));
    }
    return APIResponse<List<NewsModel>>(data: articales);
  }
  return APIResponse<List<NewsModel>>(error: true, errorMessage: data.body);
}).catchError((_) => APIResponse<List<NewsModel>>(
        error: true, errorMessage: 'An error occured'));
```

}

and this is my function

```
Future byCategories() async {
_userCategorysData = await newsService.getUserCategories(widget.user!.uid);

for (int i = 0; i <= _userCategorysData.data!.length - 1; i++) {
  await newsService
      .getByCategory(_userCategorysData.data![i].category!)
      .then((value) {
    setState(() {
      _newsCategoryData = value;
    });
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `_newsCategoryData` with a new value each time the loop executes, so when the loop is done, it will contain the last value.

I assume `_newsCategoryData` is a list in this case; use `_newsCategoryData.addAll(value)` instead of `_newsCategoryData = value` to add new data without discarding existing data.

On another note, if you must call `setState` in an asynchronous function, be sure to check `mounted` first, as the widget may have been removed from the tree by the time `setState` is called.

Comment: ok now I understand the problem, thank you for your answer

Comment: but am getting this error now "Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_newsCategoryData@40359302' has not been initialized."

Comment: Assign it to an empty list instead of making it `late`.

Comment: thank you so much its working perfectly now